# How to run a project on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I am a beginner to node.js and i did a sample code it shown below,

```
  var http = require("http");
  var server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {
    "content-Type" : "text/html"
   });
  response.end("Hello again");
 }).listen(8888);
```

and when i run this file on eclise Run as ------>  Node project
and when i open the browser with url localhost:8888 it shows web page not availble. can u guys help me to find out. I already installed node.js on my system and npm alse. am i missing something?

Comment: ` }).listent(8888);` I think you mean `listen`

Comment: @N.J.Dawson i corrected that mistake again it show web page not available

Answer (score 2):

There is no `request` or `response` object in the scope of your request callback. You need to define them as arguments of the callback function.

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    "content-Type" : "text/html"
  });
  response.end("Hello again");
}).listen(8888);
```

You should definitely get an error though - are you sure your IDE is set up properly?

Comment: i just installed enide plugin on eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You never accept the "request" variable. Below is a working version of what you're attempting.

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', function(request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {
    "content-Type" : "text/html"
   });
  response.end("Hello again");
});

server.listen(8888);
```

Comment: Except he does: [check the docs for createServer](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener). The first argument can be the request handler.

Comment: @Gant I did check the docs, but missed that, he doesn't define the param to receive "request" is probably more accurate then

Comment: @Gant not sure if you're being sarcastic or not, you seem to be a very curt fellow. If the edit makes the content makes sense, I have no idea what the problem is with it being "minimalistic"

Comment: @N.J.Dawson i tried your code it shows web page not available

Comment: @user3189828 running just that code & accessing localhost:8888 returns a webpage with "Hello again" for me - as Gant said, have you got it set up correctly in terms of development environment?

Comment: @N.J.Dawson yes i did... or can u list the steps for creating node application i will check i missed something

Comment: @N.J.Dawson i'm not sarcastic (not sarcastic), I'd never be sarcastic (sarcastic).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell me where you found `response` object? `http.createServer` return a callback function which have two arguments. They are `response` and `request`. response use for send data/information to client and request use for get data/information from client. So in your `http.createServer` callback function add response and request arguments. After that in callback function use `response` object. Like this.

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        "content-Type" : "text/html"
    });
    response.end("Hello again");
 }).listen(8888);
```